# Installing Ubuntu 64bit on Acer netbook causes black screen.

Tags: 12.04, installation, troubleshooting, alternate

Trying to install Ubuntu on an external usb 3 500 Gb hard-drive. I am using Acer netbook. My specs are: amd C-60 1GHz with 4 Gb ram. I have a 64 bits windows 7 no2 installed.

I downloaded "ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-amd64" ISO file and used the universal usb installer to install Ubuntu.

When I reboot on the external hard drive, I have the language selection, then the menu...I choose to install...and I get a black flickering screen. and nothing more.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get to the install screen press the function key to select option (look on the far right at the bottom) and select nomodeset.  Continue with the install.

Comment: ok found what was my problem...silly me...i was trying to install on my external hard-drive from my external hardrive....with to usb key, it worked....until...I got stuck with a prompt line...were i was able to log...but still get a prompt line :(

Comment: well...i fanlally found out my trouble....i did not have the good version to install...thant you Fabricator for you help.